# Activity that meant to retrieve data from it self crash

Tags: java, android

On click a button , the same activity start again but with new string , it means that i'm refreshing the same activity but with a  new value for the string (str) , The problem is that the activity is the main activity that lunch when the application start , it crashes because the retrieve code :

```
String str = getIntent().getExtras().getString("catagory").toString();
```

Maybe the reason is because by default there is no Intent yet , how to solve this ? and how to put this in a way that not causing the application to crash.

Comment: We need more context here.

Comment: Cant understand your question..!!

Comment: post logcat error and more code

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is no intent so you are most likely accessing the null pointer. Android allows you to store (key, value) pairs for an applications using the [SharedPreferences API](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)... maybe this is what you were looking for: you can store data on the device and whan the application starts, you can read the data.

Answer (score 0):

when you run this application first time, str gets null value as there is no intent passed.

thus, try this code,

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
        // do your work
}
else
{
// do your work
}
```

For the first time it will go in else, whereas later on it will call if